# Why is sql not opening (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I installed sql by using command, but I am not able to open it? Why doesn't mysql load when I run the command?

Here is the command and output:

```
user@wazeemc:~$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you used a wrong password.

If you need to reset the password follow these steps:

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
mysql -u root
```

Then you can reset the password for root

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
SET PASSWORD FOR root@'localhost' = PASSWORD('password');
```

Finally restart the service

```
pkill mysqld
sudo service mysql start
```

As described in [MysqlPasswordReset](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset)

Comment: fine Ill trust you :D

Comment: Please be sure to also stop `mysql` and start it up normally once you've done this.  If you're not clear how to accomplish this, just restart the machine.  **It is important that you do not leave mysql running as described here for any longer than needed.**

Comment: @earthmeLon edited the answer ;)